# Which @HostListener to use in a directive to listen to a form control reset/setValue?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, event-listener, form-control

I use a reactive form. My input is binded to a control and to a directive which format the control value (and thus the input value).

At some point I use the method `myInputControl.reset(myValue)`, so I want the directive to be triggered in order to format `myValue`, but I can not find the right listener to use in the directive. The listeners I have tried are listed below :

```js
export class MyDirective implements OnInit {

    constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.ngControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => { // Never fired
            this.format(this.ngControl.value);
        });
        this.ngControl.control.valueChanges.subscribe(() => { // Never fired
            this.format(this.ngControl.value);
        });
        this.ngControl.valueAccessor.registerOnChange(() => { // Never fired
            this.format(this.ngControl.value);
        });
    }

    @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event']) // Fired when manually changing the input value, but before "input" event
    onNgModelChange(event) {
        this.format(event);
    }

    @HostListener('input', ["$event.target.value"]) // Fired when manually changing the input value
    onInput(value: string) {
        this.format(value);
    }

    @HostListener('change') // Fired when focusing out but before "focusout" event
    onChange() {
        this.format(this.ngControl.value);
    }

    format(value: string) {
        log("formatting...");
    }
```

Comment: I think `writeValue` method should receive `null` value on `reset`

Comment: Has you include in declarations of your module your directive? see your code in a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cawfqq?file=src%2Fapp%2FmyDirective.ts

Comment: @Eliseo : Thank you. Considering your stackblitz, if "ngModelChange" and "subscribe" are not fired during "reset" in my case, it is because I call "reset" before the directive is initialized. Indeed, my input is inside a hidden modal. The modal's "open" method first display the modal using "display=true", and then emit an event which I use to call "reset" on the control. Unfortunately, the input directive is not initialized right after "display=true" as I thought, but after the "open" method is over, and thus after "reset" has been called. I now have to find a way to get around this behavior.